# Find the centre point of a PCB board?

Tags: altium, layout

Is there a smarter way to find the centre of a board in Altium? I just used linear dimensions to find the midpoints and the intersections.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your origin (as it appears) is at 0,0 and the x-y dimensions are at 90,34 then the center is at 45,17. You can click on the traces that define the board dimensions to confirm the starting and ending points precisely.

Sometimes it is advantageous to move the origin to the center (or elsewhere), either temporarily or permanently.

Sometimes it is useful to put a mechanical layer or silk screen layer cross at the center or some other point of interest.

Answer (score 10):

You can also draw two diagonals, as shown below. Their intersection point will be the centrepoint of the board. As you can see, you were slightly off in your calculations.

If I want to mark some point without too much visual clutter, I like use work guides, you can place one from Place > Work Guides menu.

[image]

Comment: Good tip on the work guides. +1